# OpenType Layout tables used in font ArialMT are not implemented in PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox, magnolia

I'm using the CMS Magnolia in one of our projects. In the log files there are many errors like:

OpenType Layout tables used in font ArialMT are not implemented in PDFBox

What impact has this on a PDF? Can it be opened? Does it look 'nice' or is it some kind of broken?

Answer (score 3):

This is an INFO if you are using the current version (2.0.11). It is only relevant if you use PDFBox to create PDFs, it means that certain advanced font features (GDEF, GSUB, GPOS) are not (yet) supported. You'll need these for certain languages e.g. Thai or Arabic or Indian languages. It can also be used for ligatures in latin languages (fl, fi, ffl, ffi).

Some work on this topic is being done in [PDFBOX-4189](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4189), but there is still a lot to do.

Answer (score 3):

As for Magnolia, PDFBox is used either in indexing of pdf documents or in generating preview of pdf. For first use case error is completely irrelevant, for the second it might mean that preview is not as accurate as it could be. Nothing major tho either. You can reconfigure log4j to stop seeing this error.